# How to apply cauchy's residue theorem to rational function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, laurent-series

I have the following function:
$$f(z)=\frac{(z-1)^2}{z*(z+1)^3)}$$

And I need to find its residue.

The formula that I know for this is the following:

The residue $a_{-1}$ for a pole of order "n" is:
$$a_{-1} =\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac{\partial^{n-1}(z-z_0)^{n}(f(z))}{\partial z^{n-1}}$$

Now, when I apply this to the function $f(z)$ above, I'm getting the following:

$$a_{-1} =\frac{1}{(3-1)!} \lim_{z \rightarrow -1} \frac{\partial^{3-1}(z-z_0)^{3}(f(z))}{\partial z^{3-1}}$$
$$a_{-1} =\frac{1}{2} \lim_{z \rightarrow -1} 2z - 2 = -2$$

However, I'm told that the answer is $-4$.  Where did I go wrong in my solution?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you get $2z-2$?

Answer (score 2):

I get $-1$ for the residue.  $$(z+1)^3f(z)= \frac{(z-1)^2}{z}=z-2+\frac1z$$  The second derivative is $2z^{-3}$ and $\lim_{z\to-1}\frac12\cdot2z^{-3}=-1$.

Alternatively, we want the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{z+1}$ term in the Laurent series fo $f(z)$.  We have $$\frac{(z-1)^2}{z} = z-2+\frac1z = (z+1)-3-\frac{1}{1-(z+1)}$$  Dividing by $(z+1)^3$, we see that we want the coefficient of $(z+1)^2$ in the Taylor series for $-\frac{1}{1-(z+1)}$, which is $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna rewrite the limit and work through it. So we can get the residue of a pole of order m with the following:

$$Resf(z)=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}[(z-z_0)^mf(z)]$$

Given the following $f(z)$:

$$f(z)=\frac{(z-1)^2}{z(z+1)^3}$$

Thus calculating the residue at $z=-1$ for the given $f(z)$ is as follows:

$$Resf(z)=\frac{1}{(3-1)!}\lim_{z\to -1}\frac{d^{3-1}}{dz^{3-1}}[(z-(-1))^{3}f(z)]$$

Which when simplified is:

$$Resf(z)=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to -1}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left[(z+1)^3\frac{(z-1)^2}{z(z+1)^3}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to -1}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left[\frac{(z-1)^2}{z}\right]$$

Thus taking the second derivative of the function within the limit will result in the following:

$$Resf(z)=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to -1} 2z^{-3}=\lim_{z\to -1} z^{-3}=-1$$

I had originally gotten -4 as my answer, but upon further inspection realized I made a mistake and so this is my revised answer. I know @saulspatz already gave this solution but in case you wanted a second opinion here it is lol.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question @AlejandroJimenezTellado:  I noticed that you cancelled the $(z+1)^3$ in the numerator and the denominator *before* you evaluated the derivative.  Why is it that you are allowed to evaluate the derivative after cancelling?  if it is always possible to do that, then it is true that those will always cancel, correct?

Comment: As a follow-up question, Do we know that this is a pole of order 3 before we begin this problem? Or do we need to try different values of "m" before determining the order of the pole?